# How to get the funds available at a script using Plutus?

Tags: plutus, haskell

I am currently working on Lecture 8 in the Plutus Pioneer program.

I want to view funds available at a script address.

There appears to be a function that makes this easy in [Ledger.AddressMap](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-ledger/src/Ledger/AddressMap.hs#L96-L98)

```
-- | Get the funds available at a particular address.
fundsAt :: Address -> Lens' AddressMap UtxoMap
fundsAt addr = at addr . non mempty
```

However, I have not been able to get this to work.

When I try this

```
fundsAt scriptAddress
```

I get the following error

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘f0’ arising from a use of ‘fundsAt’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Prelude.Functor f0)’ from being solved.
```

My attempts at trying to make the type unambiguous have not worked, and I am struggling to understand `Lens'`.

Does anyone know how to get the `fundsAt` function to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do this in your offchain code, I would suggest using [`Plutus.Contract.utxoAt`](https://alpha.marlowe.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-contract/html/Plutus-Contract.html#v:utxoAt) instead.

[Here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week02/src/Week02/Gift.hs#L58) is an example of it being used in the gift code.

Comment: I did see that example, but is there a reason why that's a better approach? It seems like `fundsAt` is a clearer and more direct way to get the data I want and I'm just struggling with the `Lens'` type.

Comment: They both give you a `UtxoMap`. Notice that the return type of the `grab` function is the `Contract` monad, just like `utxoAt`. It's what's meant to be used in the off-chain transaction-building code. I doubt there is a conversion between `Lens'` and `Contract`.